# How can I install script distributions from CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

I tried:

```
cpan> i /xls2csv/
No objects found of any type for argument /xls2csv/

cpan> install xls2csv
Warning: Cannot install xls2csv, don't know what it is.
Try the command

i /xls2csv/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

I haven't had any problems installing registered modules, e.g.

```
cpan> install DateTime
```

It is just the xls2csv that is providing problems.

Thank you for any insights provided.

P.S. Constrained To Windows with ActivePerl 5.10 (I think)  Also I have the xls2csv-1.06.tar.gz file downloaded and tried 
cpan> install C:/...path to file locally/xls2csv-1.06.tar.gz

That did not seem to work, and I must install locally.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The indexes used by CPAN.pm are all module-oriented, so they don't see distributions that contain no modules.  (xls2csv has only a script.)  You can still install them by giving the full path (under authors/id) of the distribution, just as you would to install older or development versions of a distribution:

```
cpan> install K/KE/KEN/xls2csv-1.06.tar.gz
```

Comment: Tried this last night and it worked perfectly.  Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Ugh...Can you suggest how one might do this on Windows?

Comment: Windows should be no different.

Answer (score 1):

It's a 5 year old script with few tests (7) none on a Mac, and one bug report (a year old). It appears to not have been updated since it was written so use this script with realistic expectations. In other words, don't be surprised if you can't get it to work.

Comment: The bug report is complaining about a documented feature.  And there's plenty of 5+ year old code on cpan that Just Works; if anything, multiple releases over time for a single-purpose distribution are an indication of instability.

Comment: @ysth: it depends on what you think instability is and how long the time is. No updates is also a sign that nobody ever used it and the code sucks. Both views are nothing but over-reaching generalizations.

Comment: Also, note that some modules with a lot of tests, no bug reports, and released last week might be more useless than this script. Heck, I might have even wrote one of those modules. There is a lot of good stuff out there that nobody knows about, and a lot of bad stuff that gets a lot of attention.

Comment: Offering my opinion of keeping his expectations realistic and that the module might not work for him is very reasonable given the circumstances. If it does work, all the better. This is not a general comment about CPAN or the code posted on CPAN. Its targeted to this one specific module and this one particular person that wants to try it.

Comment: @kevinadc - it made more sense to me as a general comment about CPAN and its code; a quick glance at the dependencies, code, and documentation of this script (and reading the bug report) lead me to think there's less to fear in this case than some random CPAN distribution, not more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using my cpan(1) command, you can also install whatever is in the current working directory by telling it to install ".".

```
% cpan .
```

That should trigger the normal CPAN.pm process for handling dependencies and so on. You should be able to do that in the CPAN.pm shell too.

If you want to fetch the file from a CPAN mirror, you can do it as ysth suggested. You give it the path under *authors/id* in the repository and CPAN.pm will find it for you. You're skipping the step where it looks in the PAUSE index because you've already given it the path to download.